# Unable to Obtain EK Certificate from TPM 2.0

Tags: certificate, tpm, tpm-2.0, remote-attestation, nvram

I want to design a system where, from the client side, when I send the EK certificate to the server, the EK public key, which is already on the server side, can be used to verify the integrity of the certificate to confirm it originates from the same TPM.

for that, I need to generate an Endorsement Key (EK) using TPM 2.0, and then obtain an EK certificate from the TPM manufacturer.

I have created the ek public using

```
sudo tpm2_createek -G rsa -u ek.pub -c 0x81010001
```

How can I obtain the EK certificate from TPM?

update:

```
systemctl start tpm-server.service
udo systemctl start tpm2-abrmd.service
sudo tpm2_createek -G rsa -u ek.pub -c key.ctx

tpm2_getekcertificate -X -o ECcert.bin -u ek.pub https://tpm.manufacturer.com/ekcertserver/
```

got this error:

```
saman@dell-5590:~$ sudo tpm2_getekcertificate -X -o ECcert.bin -u ek.pub https://tpm.manufacturer.com/ekcertserver/
WARN: TLS communication with the said TPM manufacturer server setup with SSL_NO_VERIFY!
ERROR: curl_easy_perform() failed: SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK
ERROR: Unable to run tpm2_getekcertificate
```

Comment: This resource might be helpful: https://tpm2-software.github.io/2020/06/12/Remote-Attestation-With-tpm2-tools.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a dedicated [tool](https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tools) `tpm2_getekcertificate` provided by tpm2-tools.

See [this example](https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tools/blob/master/man/tpm2_getekcertificate.1.md#examples) from the man pages:

```bash
tpm2_createek -G rsa -u ek.pub -c key.ctx

tpm2_getekcertificate -X -o ECcert.bin -u ek.pub \
https://tpm.manufacturer.com/ekcertserver/
```

Under the hood, the tool reads the RSA EK certificate from TPM nonvolatile memory (NVRAM). The RSA EK certificate specifically is stored at NV index `0x01c00002`, as specified in the [TCG EK Credential Profile](https://trustedcomputinggroup.org/wp-content/uploads/TCG_IWG_Credential_Profile_EK_V2.1_R13.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A67%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C87%2C273%2C0%5D).

Comment: please see the updated part of the question.

Comment: I think the above example is for Intel fTPMs (you have to change the url, of course). If you only want to read from NV, you can try `tpm2_getekcertificate -o RSA_EK_cert.bin -o ECC_EK_cert.bin`. See the man page. I cannot verify that atm, sorry.